# how to append this div in JQUERY

Tags: jquery, html

**how to append this div in JQUERY**
im having some trouble with my JQUERY.

- PHP -------------------------

  ```
      <?php include "Header.php";
      include "Connection.php";
      //List Medecin

      $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM analyse");
      $stmt->execute();
      $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
      $i=0;
  ?>
  ```

**DIV** -----------------

```
  <div id="contun">
    <div id="listA" class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-xl-12 col-md-3 form-control-label">
    Analyse N° <?php echo ++$i; ?>
    <span class="required">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class=" col-xl-12 col-md-9">
      <select style="width:534px; height:36px;" class="form-control" data-plugin="select2">
      <option> </option>
      <?php
      foreach($rows as $row){ 
      echo "<option value=".$row['Id_A'].">".$row['Type_A']."</option>";
      }
      ?>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Button-------------------------

```
<div id="ADD_div" class="form-group col-xl-12 text-left padding-top-m">
    <h1  class="btn btn-primary">+</h1>
</div>
```

SCRIPT--------------------------------------------

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#ADD_div").click(function (e){
        $('#contun').append($('#listA'));
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please describe your issue more clearly. Which div? Append to what? When?

Comment: I'm failing to see how PHP figures into this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

append function should take HTML as a parameter, so you have to get the `div` HTML using `$('#listA').html()`.

Check updated code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ADD_div").click(function(e) {
    $('#contun').append($('#listA').html());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contun">
  <div id="listA" class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-xl-12 col-md-3 form-control-label">
    <span class="required">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class=" col-xl-12 col-md-9">
      <select style="width:534px; height:36px;" class="form-control" data-plugin="select2">
      <option> </option>
      <option>AA</option>
      <option>BB</option>
      <option>CC</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="ADD_div" class="form-group col-xl-12 text-left padding-top-m">
  <h1 class="btn btn-primary">+</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you just want to append more text to the end of the div?
In which case you could do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#ADD_div").click(function (e){
    $('#contun').html($('#contun').html() + "Your appended text or html");
  });
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't the `.append()` method make more sense?

Comment: Yeah as you can probably tell, I misunderstood what he wanted, I feel like an idiot now reading the correct answer above which wasn't there when I answered. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Don't worry about it. Considering how unclear this question is, I'm not sure anyone is 100% sure what the OP wants :-)